# withCredentials oboe request

Tags: angularjs, curl, xmlhttprequest

I am currently working with a Neo4j graph database that offers REST url's for free. And I am trying to hook it up to a angular module that provides Oboe client side streaming: https://github.com/RonB/angular-oboe

I am trying to better understand how to add username:password credentials in my request header in an effort to transcribe this curl command

```
> curl --user username:password http://localhost:7474/auth/list
```

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension

In the Usage section of the angular-oboe README, it outlines parameters for the request

```
    $scope.myData = Oboe({
        url: '/api/myData',
        pattern: '{index}',
        pagesize: 100
    });
```

I have a hunch to add a line for withCredentials as listed on the Oboe repo
https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js-website/blob/master/content/api.md

oboe({
   url: String,
   method: String,          // optional
   headers: Object,         // optional
   body: String|Object,     // optional
   cached: Boolean,         // optional
   withCredentials: Boolean // optional, browser only
})

But I'm not sure where to put the username:password pair.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated in collaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular-oboe service passes all parameters to the Oboe function so you can specify a headers parameter. To make sure authentication is allowed on the request specify withCredentials: true.
Basic authentication can be achieved by:

```
    .controller('StreamingCtrl', function($scope, Oboe) {
        $scope.contacts = [];
        // the contacts streamed
        $scope.contacts = Oboe({
            url: 'http://some.restfull.srv/contacts',
            pattern: '{contactid}',
            pagesize: 100,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                // Base 64 encoded Basis authentication
                Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')
            }
        });
    })
```

The btoa function will Base 64 encode the username and password.

Edit:
The angular-oboe factory has been altered since the first answer and is returning a promise instead of the array of json objects.

This is how to use the latest version:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller(['$scope', 'Oboe', function($scope, Oboe) {
        $scope.myData = [];
        Oboe({
            url: '/api/myData',
            pattern: '{index}',
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Authentication: 'Basic '  + btoa('yourusername:yourpassword')
            }
        }).then(function() {
            // finished loading
        }, function(error) {
            // handle errors
        }, function(node) {
            // node received
            $scope.myData.push(node);
        });
    }]);
```